# Why does this code using shadowing `let` bindings hang?

Tags: haskell, scope, let, letrec

Running this code:

```
j = let x = 4
    in let x = x * x
       in x
```

in the interpreter:

```
ghci> j
... no response ...
```

hangs with very little CPU utilization.  Why is this?  I expected `j = 16`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the Haskell report, [section 3.12](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-440003.12):

> Let expressions have the general form let { d1 ; … ; dn } in e, and introduce a nested, lexically-scoped, mutually-recursive list of declarations **(let is often called letrec in other languages)**. The scope of the declarations is the expression e and the right hand side of the declarations.

*(emphasis mine)*

So in the second `let`, where `x = x * x`, all `x`s refer to the same binding, *none* refer to the outer `x = 4` binding.